# get data from xml url using php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get data from xml url using php but its not working for me. Please check what is wrong in my code.

```
$result_xml = simplexml_load_file(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=UB67JJ"
);

echo $result_xml->GeocodeResponse->result->formatted_address;
```

I want to get "formatted_address" from xml file.

Comment: What about just `$result_xml->result->formatted_address;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know where the `GeocodeResponse` comes from, but it is not in the XML response.
It should just be

```
echo $result_xml->result->formatted_address;
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: now its giving error;

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0

Comment: I just used $explod_postcode = $result_xml->result->formatted_address; in session like this $_SESSION['session_area'] = $explod_postcode; and then its giving me that error.

Comment: anyway thank you so much for that great help but its working for me in alternative way.

Comment: however, the error is that the SimpleXMLElement assigned to the SESION can not be stored (to the session store). Simple workaround is to implicitly call __toString by : $_SESSION['area'] = ''.$explode_postcode;

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right, the $result_xml already referes to the outer xml-container, so try:

```
echo $result_xml->result->formatted_address;
```